# How can I remove/replace mutiple strings using wildcard?

Tags: mysql

I have drafts in Wordpress (MySQL) that contain multiple img tags each, in the following format:

```
<img ... />
```

I want to remove all of those img tags entirely. I thought the REPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE functions would be suited for this, not sure if it's the best solution.

One approach I thought of is:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<img % />', '')
WHERE post_status = "Drafts";
```

But when I try that it doesn't change any posts.

Any thoughts on how that can be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: REPLACE() does not use patterns. REGEXP_REPLACE() will solve. It will be something similar to ```UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<img [^>]+ \/>', '') WHERE post_status = "Drafts";```.

Comment: It looks like you are correct. I solved it using ```'<img [^>]* />'```. Well I actually got the answer from Claude. Why don't you post your solution though - I'll accept it and close this.

Comment: You may post self-answer, with more detailed explanation and examples - this will be useful for another users.. I'm too lazy to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that worked is:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<img [^>]* />', '') 
WHERE post_status = "Drafts";
```

`REGEXP_REPLACE` was needed here so it can match all the different urls inside the different `img` tags.

Comment: Is the space before "/>" required?